# Make a curl request for xml_rpc c++ server

Tags: c++, curl, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I am trying to make a curl request for a c++ xml-rpc server. After a bit of reading, I came to know the xml-rpc request using curl will look like this

```
curl --connect-timeout 10 -d'
<xml request>
' -H 'Content-type:text/xml' https://<Billing Core server>:<Port>/RPC2
```

In my case it will be

```
curl --connect-timeout 10 -d'
<xml request>
' -H 'Content-type:text/xml' https://127.0.0.1:40405/RPC2
```

I am not sure how to fill in `<xml request>` and xml_rpc c++ code looks like this

```
class Data {
  public:
    Data();
    ~Data();

    std::string getTitle() const;
    void setTitle(std::string title);
    std::string getMessage(std::string name) const;

  private:
    std::string title;
};

class SetTitle: public xmlrpc_c::method {
  public:
    SetTitle(Data* data);
    void execute(xmlrpc_c::paramList const& paramList, xmlrpc_c::value * const retvalP);
  private:
    SetTitle(); // Hereby disabled
    Data* data;
};

void SetTitle::execute(xmlrpc_c::paramList const& paramList, xmlrpc_c::value * const retvalP) {
  string const title(paramList.getString(0));
  paramList.verifyEnd(1);

  data->setTitle(title);

  *retvalP = xmlrpc_c::value_string(title); // XML-RPC void return values are an extension to the protocol and not always available or compatible between languages.
}

serviceRegistry.addMethod("set_title", new SetTitle(data));
```

How to create xml_request ? I would like to call set_tittle function. How to fill in `Data` information in xml_request

set_title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file name `set_title.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>set_title</methodName>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value>
            <string>BhanuKiran</string>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

And made a `curl request`

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @set_title.xml -X POST http://127.0.0.1:40405/RPC2 -v
```

Here are [specs](http://xmlrpc.com/spec.md) from http://xmlrpc.com/